# Can you "allocate" stack space with VirtualAlloc?

Tags: winapi, memory-management, x86

I'm messing around with `VirtualAlloc` and dynamic code generation, and I've become curious about something.

The first parameter of `VirtualAlloc` specifies the start of the address range to be allocated, or more accurately, the *page containing that address* specifies the start of the *page range* to be allocated. Right?

I started wondering. Could you just make a bunch of space on the stack and "allocate" that memory with `VirtualAlloc`? For instance, to change its permissions to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`?

(As an extension of the above, I'm curious where exactly the stack *is* in a Windows process. How is it set up? What sets it up?)

**tl;dr** Can you "allocate" stack space with `VirtualAlloc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack space is allocated by `VirtualAlloc` and the `MEM_RESERVE` flag (or perhaps directly using the underlying syscall) when a thread is created.  This causes a chuck of the process's address space to be reserved for that thread stack.

A guard page is used to cause an access-violation when the stack grows past the region which is actually committed.  The OS handles this automatically, by committing additional memory (if there is enough reserved space) or generating `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW` to the process if the edge of the reserved area is reached.  In the first case, a new guard page is set up.  In the second, recreating the guard page is an important step if you try to handle that exception and recover.

You could use `VirtualAlloc` and `VirtualProtect` to precommit your thread's stack.  But they don't touch the stack pointer, so they can't be used for stack allocation (code using the stack pointer would happily reuse "your" allocation for automatic variables, function parameters, etc).  To allocate space from the stack, you need to adjust the stack pointer.  Most C and C++ compilers provide an `_alloca()` intrinsic for doing this.

If you're doing dynamic code generation, don't use the stack for that.  Non-executable stack is a valuable protection against remote execution vulnerabilities.  You certainly can use `VirtualAlloc` for dynamic allocation in specialized cases like this, instead of the general-purpose allocators `HeapAlloc` and `malloc` and `new[]`.  The general-purpose allocators all ultimately get their memory from `VirtualAlloc`, but then parcel it out in chunks that don't line up with page boundaries.

Comment: @Remy: I considered structuring it that way, but (1) it made the sentence very wordy and complex, and (2) it led to `(a || b && c)` ambiguity (well-defined to compiler, confusing to reader)

Comment: A [guard page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366549.aspx) does not cause an access violation, it causes a page fault. There are two very different and distinct errors, which is why I originally edited your answer.

Comment: @remy a page fault is something very specific, it means that no mapping at all exists for a page, in either the TLB or the page tables found via CR3. The guard page documentation you linked provides no hints as to how it is implemented, by rescinding access in the active page table or by removing the PTE entirely. (Naturally it still exists in the OS data structures along with the correct access flags)

Comment: Read the documentation again more carefully: "If a program attempts to access an address within a guard page, the system raises a `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` (0x80000001) exception. The system also clears the `PAGE_GUARD` modifier, removing the memory page's guard page status. The system will not stop the next attempt to access the memory page with a `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` exception."

Comment: page fault, guard fault, to-ma-to, tom-a-to :)  It is still not an access violation, which your answer claims.

Comment: "Accesses using linear addresses may cause page-fault exceptions (#PF; exception 14). An access to a linear address may cause page-fault exception for either of two reasons: (1) there is no translation for the linear address; or (2) there is a translation for the linear address, but its access rights do not permit the access."  All of type (2) can be correctly called access violations, but they aren't all exposed to the application as `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, some surface as `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW`, some surface as `EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE`, and some are handled internally.